# Terraform destroy not deleting the aws VPC

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to provision a EKS cluster using terraform. As per the [terraform tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/eks?in=terraform/kubernetes)

When I run the terraform destroy, it should delete all the resources.

I provisioned the eks cluster and all the nodes got deployed. But after running the  `terraform destroy`, the terraform script showed 51 resource destroyed but when I say in the aws console, neither the vpc, not the subnet or routing table/nat gateway were destroy.

```
module.eks.local_file.kubeconfig[0]: Destroying... [id=6f81d992c600954c7041ddf3739d5f1252346ffc]
module.eks.kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth[0]: Destroying... [id=kube-system/aws-auth]
module.eks.local_file.kubeconfig[0]: Destruction complete after 0s
module.eks.kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth[0]: Destruction complete after 1s
module.vpc.aws_route_table_association.public[1]: Destroying... [id=rtbassoc-08c453a733ea2a5d5]
module.vpc.aws_route_table_association.private[0]: Destroying... [id=rtbassoc-0a68e69b44894837e]
module.vpc.aws_route.public_internet_gateway[0]: Destroying... [id=r-rtb-042d838411d7f5b411080289494]
...
module.eks.aws_security_group.workers[0]: Destroying... [id=sg-01fbd466903d27f1d]
module.vpc.aws_subnet.private[2]: Destruction complete after 1s
module.eks.aws_iam_role.cluster[0]: Destruction complete after 2s
module.eks.aws_security_group.workers[0]: Destruction complete after 1s
module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.cluster_egress_internet[0]: Destruction complete after 2s
module.eks.aws_security_group.cluster[0]: Destroying... [id=sg-03d192a4288698362]
module.eks.aws_security_group.cluster[0]: Destruction complete after 2s
module.vpc.aws_vpc.this[0]: Destroying... [id=vpc-03e068a4161856d05]
module.vpc.aws_vpc.this[0]: Destruction complete after 0s
random_string.suffix: Destroying... [id=tYRB2hkn]
random_string.suffix: Destruction complete after 0s
```

I had to delete them manually from the ui. So, the question is did the terraform destroy the vpc or not?

Thanks.

Comment: It says "module.vpc.aws_vpc.this[0]: Destruction complete after 0s" so unless you have multiple VPCs, it seems it got destroyed.

Comment: I think your module created another VPC for k8s and the VPC that you see in the console, is the default one, right? If so, there is no way to delete it.

Comment: It did eventually got destroyed next time round. One of the things, I suspect was, I forgot to change the region that was Ohio. and I am in eu-west-2. So, it might have taken more time to delete the resources due to network latency.